# why is my centos, nginx, php,mysql server using so much memory

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

i'm not sure where the problem lies. I have:

centos 6
mysql
php
php-fpm
wordpress (1 site).

this is a dedicated server i'm learning on.

as soon as i ran the web url the memory slammed to 125% of a 512k server, i had to upgrade to 1gig, so i'm not sure where the problem lies. I thought by switching to nginx from apache i would have more memory free, but i'm still stuck with the problem.

before launching the site with nginx and mysqld running the site was about 5% memory.

I reanamed my "my-small.cnf" to my.cnf and put in my /etc folder where the original was, but that seems not to have done it.

after looking at my TOP results, i'm starting to think it may be php-fpm eating my memory, but not sure.

is php-fpm the preferend way or is there something better to use. I read about possible memory leaks in php-fpm.

here is what i have:

php-fpm.conf

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix.

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Default Value: none
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; Default Value: /var/log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_threshold = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when 
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;process_control_timeout = 0

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
;daemonize = yes

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ; 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; See /etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

end php-fpm.conf

[image: top]

[image: admin panel]

[image: gui-top]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nginx + PHP 5.3.3 (with php-fpm) - memory usage?](http://serverfault.com/questions/173821/nginx-php-5-3-3-with-php-fpm-memory-usage)

Comment: read that already

Comment: So what did you learn from it? Did you try to lower your php memory values and the maximum amount of children? Wordpress is quite memory hungry as well.

Comment: that's wiat i need to know, i wan't aware that wordpress was a memory hog. maybe that's my issue, becaue i've tried everything and nothing. only a php-fpm restart drops memory a bit, but children aren't high.

Comment: It also might be a memory leak, but you can't notice that unless you test it for a few days and watch the memory consumption.

Comment: That top output shows you've got a GB of memory free.  It's useless for determining where you're using memory.  Also, sort by memory usage (`M`) to find the heavy users.  Finally, Virtuozzo sucks as a virtualisation platform for uncoordinated guests; don't expect this to be the last mysterious performance problem you have.

Comment: it shows 1GB because i had to temporarly upgrade. i want to run at 512 because it costs more to run a GB. at 512 its unusable memory slams 125% with no load. like i said i did everything my adjusting php, and mysql for memory, plus the extra free mem shown is burstable, not regular use

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score -1):

The best solution would be to add this line to your cronjob that will reload every 10-60 mins (CentOS):

/etc/init.d/php-fpm reload

I have heavy WP sites running on my networkcities.com network services which works pretty well.

Comment: Whut? Seriously? Reloading the fpm runner? Could it just be that the code's shit?